# How to seperate textBox1 type action and use textBox1.Text to get string from internet?

Tags: c#, textbox, response, keydown

I'm writing a code that when I type in `textBox1`, my WinForm send `textBox1.Text` to a web server, it process the text, the return string is show as a toolTip.

My problem is when I type a character in `textBox1`, I cant type next character until the web server response. I tried with `textBox1.KeyDown`, `textBox1.KeyUp` and `textBox1.TextChanged` but they seem dont help me solve this problem.

I want when I type in `textBox1`, I dont be effected by the action get string from server.

Is any way to seperate the type action and get text form server? Thank you very much.

[Sorry for bad English]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are blocking the UI thread while you fetch the data from the server. You need to get that data on a separate thread. Check out: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229675.aspx

Comment: I have a sneaking suspicion that TuyenTk's program is trying to get a response every time the textbox changes. If that's the case, there's going to be quite the buildup of responses depending on the length of the input text.

Comment: Yes. In his dl thread he would need a slight delay before the download begins. Then if another key is hit during that delay the first request can be aborted and a new one started (with the same pre-delay).